# Html Price slider with some prices

Tags: html, css

I want price slider as shown in image.

[image]

I was able to do it partially without prices as shown in image

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
      var x=val.toString();
    var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
    var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
    if(otherNumbers != '')
        lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
    var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
          document.getElementById('textInput').value=res; 
        }
```

```html
<div class="price-slider py-4">
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100000" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<div class="price-list d-flex">
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please check this demo example https://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/rOVrGK

Comment: When user is  sliding, he can able to select  values in between  range also. In your slider it is not working

Comment: we can get the selected value from the click handler method  in  `$rangeInput.val()`    `// Change input value on label click
$('.range-labels li').on('click', function () {
  var index = $(this).index();
  
  $rangeInput.val(index + 1).trigger('input');
  alert($rangeInput.val())
});` but yes here we dont have in between value selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" list="tickmarks" id="rangeInput" oninput="output.value = rangeInput.value">
  <datalist id="tickmarks">
    <option value="0 to 20">0</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>60</option>
    <option>80</option>
    <option>100</option>
  </datalist>
  <output id="output" for="rangeInput">50</output>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
  alert($(this).val());
})
```

CSS:

```
input[type='range'] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #777, #777 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #777, #777 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #777, #777 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: 122px 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #777;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #777;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #EEE;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 210px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #777;
  color: #777;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background: #EEE;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #EEE;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
}
input[type='range']:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/*input[type='range']:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '20 40 60 80';
  padding: 25px 4035px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}*/

.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  color: #777;
  content: '20 40 60 80';
  padding: 40px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.container {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

output{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #777;
}
output:before{
  content:"Selected Value: ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
body {
  font-family: Calibri, Arial;
}
```

Working demo url:
https://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/BNyzvj/